# Connect to cloudways mysql db with microsoft access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ssh, cloudways

I have been trying to create an SSH tunnel in order to connect a microsoft access frontend to a mysql database on my cloudways server. I have successfully connected to it and tested the mysql connection through putty, however it does not appear to let me connect to the DB on the ODBC with Microsoft Access. Not sure why it is not accepting the ip/port as local host.

Comment: Can you create an ODBC "System DSN" that connects to the MySQL database, then try using that DSN to define an ODBC linked table in Access?